# what is the meaning of shell title?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm new to linux. And I'm confused with the different shell titles in linux.

for example, when I called "/bin/sh", I saw

```
sh-3.1#
```

but when I used "su root", I saw

```
my-environment:~#
```

and when I logged in as normal user, I saw

```
user@my-environment:$
```

I kind of notice # means root and $ means non-root, but could some explain how I got the above titles?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those are called "prompts". In each session: `echo "$PS1"` and read http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your variable environment `$PS1`.

To see what I mean, try doing `PS1=something`, and see what happens.

To reset it you could do `source ~/.bashrc`.

So, why do you have different prompt according? Because you don't load the same files according to the command you type to open your sessions, so you end up with different configs, hence a different `$PS1`

Answer (score 1):

The text at the shell prompt is controlled by the variable `$PS1` (and sometimes `$PS2 $PS3 $PS4`). [This blogpost](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/) explains how you can customize the prompt in many ways.

Do `echo $PS1` in the different terminals to see the current value.